# Unable to start IIS after Windows 10 creators update

Tags: iis, windows-10, iis-10

After upgrading to Windows 10 creators update, I noticed that IIS was no longer in my system. So I went ahead and installed IIS from "Turn Windows Features on or off" feature in Control Panel. While I was at it, I also checked all boxes related to IIS and .Net framework.

After restarting my machine after the install, IIS came back with all the websites I configured earlier but all of them are stopped. When I attempt to start them, I get this message:

> Websites cannot be started unless both the Windows Activation Service
>   (WAS) and the World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) are running.
>   Both services are currently stopped.

Looking at services, I can only see `World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)` in disabled state but `Windows Activation Service` is missing. Attempting to start W3SVC shows an error message:

> Windows could not start the World Wide Web Publishing Service service
>   on Local Computer. Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed
>   to start.

Can someone please help me get my IIS running as before? Appreciate your time and help.